# Servicestack.net custom XML DateTime serialization

Tags: datetime, xml-serialization, servicestack-bsd

Is there a way to override the XML DateTime serialization in Servicestack.Net like we can do with JSON:

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = date => new DateTime(date.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

I want to do the same thing for all XML DateTimes.

**Edit:**

I just found out I can hook into the XML serialization with this:

```
this.ContentTypeFilters.Register("application/xml", SerializeXmlToStream, DeserializeXmlFromStream);


public static void SerializeXmlToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, object response, Stream stream)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {

        sw.Write(response.ToXml());
    }
}
```

This returns the same XML as without this hook. If someone has any idea how I can change the serialiazation of DateTime to a custom format with this or any other global way please let me know.

Comment: @mythz is there a simple way to handle this in servicestack.net > 4?